# Tensorflow Applying SyncReplicasOptimizer to seq2seq model with buckets

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I was applying data parallelism to [seq2seq](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py) model, which implement several sub-graph for each pre-defined buckets respectively. and it handles its gradients like below:

```
# buckets = [(10,15),(20,25)..]
self.gradient_norms = []
self.grads = []
self.updates = []
self.opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
for b in xrange(len(buckets)):
    gradients = tf.gradients(self.losses[b], params)
    clipped_gradients, norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients,...)
    self.gradient_norms.append(norm)
    self.updates.append(opt.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, params), global_step=self.global_step))
.......
.....
output_feed = [self.updates[bucket_id], 
               self.gradient_norms[bucket_id],
               self.losses[bucket_id]]
```

According to the instructions in [`sync_replicas_optimizer.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py) all  I need is to wrap self.opt and use `compute_gradients()`, clip all by myself and then use the wrapped `apply_gradients()` which is implicitly distributed.

I have attempted to implement it in two different way.

1) An outter SyncReplicasOptimizer with several `apply_gradients()` in the buckets loop:

```
...
self.opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
self.sync_applys = []
self.sync_opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(self.opt,
                    replicas_to_aggregate=replicas_to_aggregate,
                    replica_id=replica_id,
                    total_num_replicas=total_num_replicas)
for b in xrange(len(buckets)):
    grad_var = self.sync_opt.compute_gradients(self.losses[b], params)
    # collect grad and clip it by myself
    for each in grad_var:
         self.grads.append(each[0])
    clipped_grad,norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(self.grads,max_gradient_norm)
    apply_gradients_op = self.sync_opt.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_grad, params), global_step=self.global_step)
    self.sync_applys.append(apply_gradients_op)
    ......
    ....
    output_feed = [self.losses[bucket_id]],
                   self.sync_applys[bucket_id],
                   self.sync_opt._local_steps,
                   self.sync_opt._global_step]
```

but in this way, all the process on all the machines get stuck once enter the main loop.

2) An inner SyncReplicasOptimizer for each buckets:

```
sync_opts = []
for b in xrange(len(buckets)):
    sync_opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(self.opt,
                replicas_to_aggregate=replicas_to_aggregate,
                replica_id=replica_id,
                total_num_replicas=total_num_replicas)
    for each in grad_var:
         self.grads.append(each[0])
    clipped_grad,norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(self.grads,max_gradient_norm)
    apply_gradients_op = sync_opt.apply_gradients(...)
    self.sync_opts.append(sync_opt)
    .....
    ...
    output_feed = [self.losses[bucket_id],
                   self.sync_applys[bucket_id],
                   self.sync_opts[bucket_id]._local_steps,
                   self.sync_opts[bucket_id]._global_step]
```

but in this way i get a ppx toward to be infinite both on my training and valid set.

In my case, I have 1 ps and 5 workers(chief is 0), my `total_replicas` and `replicas_to_aggregate` are the same.

The SyncReplicasOptimizer will create queues and some other variables when the `apply_gradients()` is called. and I don't know whether it'll cause any sync problems when it comes to the multi-buckets-in-one-machine issue, since at every run-time step, only one sub-graph(bucket) according to the length of input will be chosen and it has its own "sync objects" created by `SyncReplicasOptimizer.apply_gradients()`

Can any one give me some advice about that, or have better ways for seq2seq data parallelism?

All I have resorted to:
tensorflow distributed guidelines
Cifar10 distributed examples